# Codeigniter 2 com erro de referência de variável na versão 5.6 do PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Estou usando a versão 2.1.3 do Codeigniter e quando abro qualquer página o seguinte erro é exibido:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 257

Na linha  `257` tem um código estranho:

```
return $_config[0] =& $config;
```

Essa mensagem começou a ser exibida desde que atualizei a versão do PHP para 5.6.

Por que esse erro ocorre? Como posso resolvê-lo?

Comment: Por que o framework usa tecnicas arcaicas ...

Comment: @rray e agora, quem poderá nos defender?

Comment: Acabei de achar essa linha kkk.

Comment: Tenso é se eu tiver que mexer no código-fonte :\

Comment: é pq vc não viu a lib de upload .... e sim tem mexer no framework ...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters isso foi resolvido na 2.2.1 : https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/69b02d0f0bc46e914bed1604cfbd9bf74286b2e3

Comment: Atualize a versão... Essas coisas não acontecem mais...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O framework Codeigniter tem um grande legado, então utiliza algumas técnicas que caíram em desuso. O problema nesse caso é o `&` na assinatura do método `get_config()`, que obriga o retorno a ser uma referência (variável).

Se você conseguir medir o impacto da alteração, outra solução é remover o `&` da assinatura. Como esse trecho de código faz parte (`Comum`/ `Common` ;) ) do framework, pode acarretar comportamentos inesperados.

Assinatura:

```
function &get_config($replace = array())
```

Mude:

```
return $_config[0] =& $config;
```

Para: conforme foi corrigido na [versão 2.2.x](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/69b02d0f0bc46e914bed1604cfbd9bf74286b2e3)

```
$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

Uma forma de simples de reproduzir o erro é com o seguinte código:

```
function &olaMundo(){
    return 'Ola mundo';
}

echo olaMundo(); //Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference in
```

Correção:

```
function &olaMundo(){
    $x = 'Ola mundo';
    return $x;
}
```

[Exemplo funcional](https://3v4l.org/ZbXSD) rodado em várias versões do php.